# Trigger in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I want to create a trigger in oracle.
When someone inserts on the table the trigger should change one element of the insert statement. Example:

Someone inserts:

```
"User1" "Road2" "Town2" "Age44"
```

my trigger should do:

```
"User1 "Road2" "Town2 "**Age35**"
```

But this should not be something like

```
"after insert on table1 begin update table1 set age='Age35'"
```

I need something that does it instantly so like "instead of insert on table1 begin insert into table1 values "User" "Road" "Town" "Age35"

so that the trigger only change one element of the insert and the rest is equal. I really appreciate any help you guys can provide. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @SemihEker - in what way and to what purpose did you want OP to edit this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it before the insert:

```
create table test (myuser varchar2(100), age number);
create or replace trigger test_trigger 
before insert on test
referencing new as new 
for each row
begin
  if :new.age = 45 then 
     :new.age := 35;
  end if;
end;
/
insert into test values ('user1',45);
insert into test values ('user2',46);
select * from test;
```

Output:

```
Table created.
Trigger created.
1 row created.
1 row created.

    MYUSER         AGE
----------  ----------
user1               35                                                              
user2               46

2 rows selected.
```

**EDIT:**

You can also use the `WHEN`. But you cannot avoid doing it row by row. You do not get the whole insert statement somehow and manipulate on it. There is no `instead of trigger` for tables.

```
create or replace trigger test_trigger 
    before insert on test
    referencing new as new 
    for each row
    when(new.age = 45)
    begin
      :new.age := 35;
    end;
    /
```

Regarding the performance concerns I think you should really try it out. I do not think it will be so a negative impact really.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that my table has ~500000k rows. If i understand this right he will check every row thats not acceptable in terms of performance. I just need to change the row that i want to insert.

Comment: Because you mentioned you want a trigger so I gave you a trigger. But I am not sure if you will have such a perfomance problem if you insert 1/2 million rows you will get the trigger run through half a million times. You should try it out and then you can think about tuning if there is a problem. Do not assume there is one in the first place. What is your use case? Do you insert or do other programs not under your control insert?Before commit no visibility to other users, so maybe you can insert, then update and then commit, without a trigger at all.

Comment: Yeah a program inserts. And i cant change the program code. So i have to change what this program does. I think the easiest way is when you can do some variables in the trigger. like you do when you programm in java or something. so they will be filled with the stuff the program inserts and i do a trigger with the insert command. So i can use the variables in the insert and delete the one i want to have the same numer every time. Maybe you know if something like that is possible.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I finally got time to try out your solution. The performance was ok. So your solution works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "before insert" instead of "after insert" to edit the value of the Age variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it isnt that easy i guess. When i use before insert the row will not be changed because its not in the table. I cant edit the row before it has been inserted.